# C++ beginner here is it possible to call a function within another function?

Tags: c++, macos

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void displayRules();
void play();
int shuffleCard(int cardPile[]);


int main()
{
    int board[26] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int cardPile[10] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 5};
    int player1 = 0;
    int player2 = 0;

    play();


    return 0;
}

void play(){
    displayRules();
    shuffleCard(cardPile);

}

void displayRules(){
    cout << "\nWelcome to GoHome! The main objective of this game is to reach Home"
            " first." << endl;
    cout << "The basic rules of the game are as follows:" << endl;
    cout << "\n-To begin the player with the shortest name goes first." << endl;
    cout << "-Each player picks a card that has a number on it and the player"
            " must moves forward that many number of spaces." << endl;
    cout << "-If a card says 'Lose A Turn', the player does nothing and the"
            "turn moves to the next player." << endl;
    cout << "-If a card says 'Switch Places', that player is allowed to switch"
            " places with any player on the board." << endl;
    cout << "-If a player lands on an obstacle, that player must move back that"
            " many number of spaces." << endl;
    cout << "-If a player lands another obstacle while moving backwards, then it"
            " does not have to move backwards again.\n"<<endl;
}

int shuffleCard(int cardPile[]){

    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            int size = rand() % 10;
        cout << cardPile[size] << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm doing a homework assignment where my professor specifically mentioned that he only wanted main to call the play function and that everything else should be done in functions.

Basically he wanted functions to call other functions. So far I have 2 functions one called play and the other called shuffleCard. My problem is that I'm not sure how to get the play function to call the shuffleCard function. The play function calls the displayRules function with no problems but when I try to compile this I get an error saying **use of undeclared identifier 'cardPile'.**

Comment: Of course it is possible. You probably missed to specify a forward declaration?

Comment: Open your C++ book, and read the chapter that explains how "forward declarations" work.

Comment: When the compiler says `use of undeclared identifier 'cardPile'` what it means is that inside `play` you are using the name (identifier) `cardPile`, but it couldn't find any such variable. You have one inside `main`, but that is not accessible from outside `main`. You would need to make another local variable `int cardPile[10] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 5};` or pass `cardPile` to `play` so it can pass it to `shuffleCard`.

Comment: Ok thank you guys I figured out what I did wrong and got it to work now!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void displayRules();
void play(int cardPile[]);
int shuffleCard(int cardPile[]);


int main()
{
    int board[26] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int cardPile[10] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 5};
    int player1 = 0;
    int player2 = 0;

    play(cardPile);


    return 0;
}

void play(int cardPile[]){
    displayRules();
    shuffleCard(cardPile);

}

void displayRules(){
    cout << "\nWelcome to GoHome! The main objective of this game is to reach Home"
            " first." << endl;
    cout << "The basic rules of the game are as follows:" << endl;
    cout << "\n-To begin the player with the shortest name goes first." << endl;
    cout << "-Each player picks a card that has a number on it and the player"
            " must moves forward that many number of spaces." << endl;
    cout << "-If a card says 'Lose A Turn', the player does nothing and the"
            "turn moves to the next player." << endl;
    cout << "-If a card says 'Switch Places', that player is allowed to switch"
            " places with any player on the board." << endl;
    cout << "-If a player lands on an obstacle, that player must move back that"
            " many number of spaces." << endl;
    cout << "-If a player lands another obstacle while moving backwards, then it"
            " does not have to move backwards again.\n"<<endl;
}

int shuffleCard(int cardPile[]){

    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            int size = rand() % 10;
        cout << cardPile[size] << endl;
    }
}
```